# Fresco setDownsampleEnabled(true) makes image muzzy when zoom

Tags: android, fresco

I config the fresco with setDownsampleEnabled(true) and use PhotoDraweeView to zoom the image.But the image is muzzy when i enlarge it.If I remove setDownsampleEnabled(true), the image shows well when i zoom out.But it will lead to other problem.Does anyone has good solution?

Comment: It sounds like downsampling is doing exactly what it is supposed to do.

Comment: But it's very strange.If I don't use it, the resizeOption won't work on png images.If I use it, the images i don't want to resize or downsample will be downsampled.

Comment: Maybe you should ask a question to figure out why resizeOption isn't working then? That seems to be your root issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I didn't get my point clear.I mean if I don't use setDownsampleEnabled(true), the resizeoption won't work on png.If i use it, all the images are downsampled including the images that I don't want them to be downsampled.

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for it? - @AllenVork

Comment: Nope. I just use Glide instead of Fresco for it has so many problems.