# Fresco - setDownsampleEnabled true/false?

Tags: java, android, android-image, fresco

I am using [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/) in my app and [initialize](http://frescolib.org/docs/configure-image-pipeline.html) it like this:

```
    DiskCacheConfig diskCacheConfig = ...

    ImagePipelineConfig imagePipelineConfig = ImagePipelineConfig.newBuilder(this)
            .setMainDiskCacheConfig(diskCacheConfig)
            .build();

    Fresco.initialize(this, imagePipelineConfig);
```

It's working fine in all cases but one: the 'huge list of large images' scrollable view. (really slow in this case).

I read the documentation about [resizing](http://frescolib.org/docs/resizing.html) and then changed Fresco initialization using **setDownsampleEnabled(true)**

```
    ImagePipelineConfig imagePipelineConfig = ImagePipelineConfig.newBuilder(this)
            .setMainDiskCacheConfig(diskCacheConfig)
            .setDownsampleEnabled(true) // faster for downsampling of big images
            .build();

    Fresco.initialize(this, imagePipelineConfig);
```

which works fine for this 'huge list of large images' view... but gives poor result for the rest, especially when I do display image full screen. Images are a bit 'muzzy' see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237023/fresco-setdownsampleenabledtrue-makes-image-muzzy-when-zoom).

**Question:**

Is it possible to use setDownsampleEnabled(true) only for a 'part' of my app?
I want the 'standard' setup for all my app, except for the 'huge list of large images' for which I want the **setDownsampleEnabled(true)**.

Maybe there is a way to configure that using ImagePipelineConfig ... ?

Frankly speaking, the current situation is almost OK, so this is not a big deal, but I would like to know if this is possible and then test to see the result.

**Note:**

I digged into Fresco code and saw this:

```
package com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline;
...
public class Fresco {
...
public static void initialize(Context context, @Nullable ImagePipelineConfig imagePipelineConfig, @Nullable DraweeConfig draweeConfig) {
    if(sIsInitialized) {
        FLog.w(TAG, "Fresco has already been initialized! `Fresco.initialize(...)` should only be called 1 single time to avoid memory leaks!");
    } else {
        sIsInitialized = true;
    }
    ...
}
...
```

´memory leaks´ .. wow..

So I do not dare to call Fresco.initialize(...) twice, once with my application, the second time for my activity in which I display the full list.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Config:
(Latest) Fresco 1.5.0

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, changing the downsampling configuration is currently not supported by Fresco. Changing this would require a couple of internal changes. Feel free to send a pull request to add this functionality :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As I wrote, current situation is good enough for me. So I'll keep things as they are now.